# how do i read from firebase into app inventor into individual spots?

Tags: android, firebase, codeblocks, app-inventor

totally new to this site and app development in general
i have been teaching myself for a couple weeks now 
been looking around for a few days now to a solution to my issue

overall plan is to create an app for my work that will allow me to scan items to make an order 
rigt now ive been trying to get the databasing stuff down

i figured out how to read and write to the Firebase database 
but the read part isnt quite working that well

*** i want to retrieve data from the database and insert or assign it into individual textboxes and or labels ***

attached are screenshots of the designer view, codeblocks and firebase page. also i have included the .aia file as well

any help would be greatly appreciated!
lemme kno if more inf is needed

thank you so much in advance!

[codeblocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aiiI.png)

[designview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9oT4.png)

[firebasedb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E10FG.png)

[dropbox link for AIA file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhfoolwerc36in8/testFirebaseDB_Demo.aia?dl=0)

Comment: What is that, is that scratch programming language? And what is the problem with reading?

Comment: @YunusKulyyev this is App Inventor, see also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/app-inventor/info

Comment: you might want to ask your question in the MIT App Inventor community https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question:

You can write and read data per tag.
[image: Example]

Make sure your ProjectBucket is correct.